# Do the Thai and Lao negative particles, "ไม่" (mai) and "ບໍ່" (bo) have reflexes in the other language?

Tags: etymology, cross-linguistic, thai, lao

In my continuing interest in this pair of closely related languages I have noticed each uses an unrleated word for the negative particle meaning "no", "not", etc.

- **Thai:** `ไม่` (mai)
- **Lao:** `ບໍ່` (bo)

Does Thai have have a reflex etymologically related to Lao "ບໍ່"? Does Lao have a reflex etymologically related to Thai "ไม่"? Do we know the origin of this difference?

Bonus question: Which words are used in Isan and Zhuang?

Comment: ບໍ່ seems to cognate with 不, much like ไม่/没. I have also heard of แล้ว/了 pair. Isaan use บ่อ for ບໍ່.

Comment: @bytebuster It sure sounds like you can submit an answer (-:

Comment: Let's keep the opportunity open to someone who can provide with some credible links. I will be happy to learn from it as well! :)

Comment: In the meantime I used your contributions in my requests for etymology on the relevant entries in Wiktionary.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn’t Thai เปล่า be the etymological equivalent of Lao ບໍ່ ?  My impression is that เปล่า is mainly used as a question tag and response, as in

เป็นหวัดหรือเปล่า? (Do you have a cold?)     เปล่า (No.)

(ไม่ would also be possible here, but sounds more formal.)

But the Longdo dictionary entry also has it in preverbal position:

นักเรียนพูดกับครูว่า ผมเปล่าลอกข้อสอบนะครับ (The student said to the teacher, “I didn’t copy the test, sir.”)

That entry also shows เปล่า being used as a content word “bare, empty, in vain” and gives the expressive pairing เปล่าเปลี่ยว “lonesome”.  So clearly there are some differences in usage from Lao.

If we’re looking for Sprachbund-type parallels, Burmese might be of interest.

chánaw thwà deh  (I go)     chánaw má thwà bù  (I don’t go)

Note the negation with má… bù, rather like a ne… pas construction in French.
Here’s the Longdo entry for เปล่า:
[Longdo](http://dict.longdo.com/search/%E0%B9%80%E0%B8%9B%E0%B8%A5%E0%B9%88%E0%B8%B2)

Comment: Hmm I certainly don't recall coming across anything in Lao that's a closer match for เปล่า so you could be right.

Comment: Then again, the Lao word for "empty" is ເປົ່າ, which does look like the reflex of เปล่า. I can't find any senses for ເປົ່າ which are not content words though.

Comment: About Zhuang:  according to Luo Yongxian in the Routledge Tai-Kadai volume, the most general negative word is bau (mid-tone), and this is “found across the Tai language family.”  If that’s the case, maybe it’s not worth speculating about เปล่า as a content word that grammaticalized.  Instead, we might focus on Thai ไม่ as an innovation or borrowing.  I checked the entry for 沒 in Axel Schuessler’s ‘ABC Etymological Dictionary of Old Chinese,’ but no leads there.  By the way, Schuessler pays quite a bit of attention to mainland Southeast Asian languages in his etymologies, esp. Austroasiatic.

Comment: As far as I know, the use of เปล่า in ผมเปล่าลอกข้อสอบนะครับ was sub-standard in Thai 30-40 years ago. Even today, it can still be considered informal at best.

Answer (score 3):

บ is used in Thai as a negative particle in poetic contexts, I think.
For example, in the บทสวดมนต์ สรภัญญะ  :
ตัดมูลเกลสมาร, บ มิหม่นมิหมองมัว
"Who have cut the roots of defilements and are not sorrowful, not dark and gloomy."
Translation source: http://paultrafford.blogspot.com/2013/03/a-buddha-prayer-song-translated.html?m=1

Comment: I think you're right.  Here's another example, from the Matichon dictionary:  เข่นฆ่ามหาอสุรแรง  ฤทธิห้าว บ ห่อนเอ   “[He] stabbed and killed the powerful asura, and his power was great [not a little]”.  This is from the poem Samuttakhote, so maybe as early as the 1680s (King Narai).